# Just display content between shortcode brackets

Tags: shortcode

I am rewriting a theme with shortcodes in the all the posts from the old theme.  I searched all the files for the original shortcode function but get no results. So in a vanilla theme the page prints

```
[shortcode dostuff]content here[/shortcode]
```

I am trying to get the shortcode to output what is between the brackets, without editing every page on the site,  so the page just shows:

```
content here
```

I can remove the shortcode with code like

```
function remove-shortcode() {   return '';}
```

but then all the content inside the brackets gets removed as well
and the page would be blank.  I tried function `remove-shortcode() {return the_content();}` and the page crashes.

What formula will return the content inside the shortcode brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have good news: the answer is simple.

The [WordPress Codex concerning Enclosing Shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/) (like the one you posted here) shows that the shortcode callback has 2 arguments, `$atts` and `$content`. You want to work with `$content`:

```
function wporg_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    // do something to $content

    // always return
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('wporg', 'wporg_shortcode');
```